# excel formula to lookup and concatenate horizontal values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Pick license plate in Sheet1 and look up on DATABASE
Then Address column should return concatenated values from location to zip (like in the red highlight)

[image: Sheet1]
[image: DATABASE]

**Thank you so much!**

Comment: Are you on excel or google sheet? If on excel then what is your excel version?

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IFERROR(FILTER(Database!$B$2:$F$5,Database!$A$2:$A$5=A2),"No Data"))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you sir but I actually use it on excel 365 ProPlus and sadly this formula doesnt work

Comment: On excel 365 it must work. Based on region you may need to use `;` semicolon instead of `,` comma inside formula.

Comment: It shows "That function isn't valid" and highlight on FILTER I think because of my version is 1808 and I cannot update due to the permission

Comment: @Helloworld Can you try this one `=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE, INDEX(TRANSPOSE(Database!$B$2:$F$5),,MATCH(A2,Database!$A$2:$A$5,0))),"No Data")` and let me know your feedback.

Comment: This show "No data" to all transaction.

Comment: @Helloworld Try to array entry with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

There are two sheets `Sheet 1` includes `license plate` and `address`, and second sheet called `DATABASE` includes `license plate`, `location`, `street`, `city`, `state`, `zip`

For Europe.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;DATABASE!$A:$F;2;FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(A2;DATABASE!$A:$F;3;FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(A2;DATABASE!$A:$F;4;FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(A2;DATABASE!$A:$F;5;FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(A2;DATABASE!$A:$F;6;FALSE);"No Data Found")
```

For US.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,DATABASE!$A:$F,2,FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(A2,DATABASE!$A:$F,3,FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(A2,DATABASE!$A:$F,4,FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(A2,DATABASE!$A:$F,5,FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(A2,DATABASE!$A:$F,6,FALSE),"No Data Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Database!B:B&" "&Database!C:C&" "&Database!D:D&" "&Database!E:E&" "&Database!F:F,MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Database!A:A,0)),"No Data")`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For old version of Excel (older than 2019).
First concatenate all address' parts in second sheet:
In "G2" of second sheet enter:

```
=CONCATENATE(B2&" "&C2&" "&D2&" "&E2&" "&F2)
```

Then in "B2" of first sheet enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$G$2:$G$6;MATCH(A2;Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6;0);"No Data")
```